# Make List only update once

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an `SwiftUI` application that displays a list of data, and a detail view.

My application currently stores thousands of records in a `FetchedResults` object as follows:

```
var items: FetchedResults<Item>
```

In my `ContentView`, I have this:

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.prop1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the user goes to the `DetailView`, he can edit all the properties of `Item`.

In `DetailView`, I have the `item` property as such:

```
@ObservedObject var item: Item
```

`Item` is declared as follows:

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var prop1: String?
    @NSManaged public var prop2: String?
    @NSManaged public var prop3: String?
}
```

Also, this is how I configure my `TextFields` to edit `item`'s properties:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    TextField("", text: Binding($item.prop1)!)
    TextField("", text: Binding($item.prop2)!)
    TextField("", text: Binding($item.prop3)!)
}
```

Now the current issue is that whenever I type something in one of the `TextFields`  in the `DetailView`, the main `List`, which houses thousands of items, refreshes. This makes typing very slow.

**How can I make my `List` not update every single item every time I change a property in the array?**

Comment: Have you tried adding the drawingGroup() modifier to your list/elements to prevent it from lagging yet?

Comment: In any TextField or only in one with `item.prop1` bound?

Comment: @SamuelDo Yes, I've tried, but it doesn't help. This is because the issue is that whenever i type something, the list has to refresh all thousands of items.

Comment: @Asperi In any text field. Everytime a property is changed, SwiftUI detects this and in return updates the thousands of items in the List

Answer (score 0):

You can make a static List that updates only once on launch by removing the ForEach.

```swift
List (items, id: \.self) { item in // << Like this
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(item.prop1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but everything remains the same. I've also updated the code (maybe it's because Item is a class?)